# Removing lines from a text file

Tags: shell

i have a text file with name `ABC.txt` contains data as

```
set_id,name,desc
1,ali,hr
2,asd,re
set_id,name,desc
```

now i want to remove all the lines with in file contains word `set_id`.

Comment: Just `set_id` or even lines containing `set_ideal` for example? Also, in the first position or anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` with `-v` for inverted search, like this:

```
grep -v "^set_id" ABC.txt
```

Or, if you want to save to a new file, do this:

```
grep -v "^set_id" ABC.txt > newfile
```

Or, if you are on Windows:

```
FINDSTR /V set_id ABC.txt > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file with sed:

```
sed -i /set_id/d ABC.txt
```

Where

```
 -i         - in-place edit (changes the source file)
 /set_id/   - matches all lines containing set_id
 d          - delete matches
```

---

*Edit*: Variants:

```
sed -i /^set_id/d ABC.txt           # Lines starting with 'set_id'
sed -i '/\<set_id\>/d' ABC.txt      # Lines containing the word 'set_id'
sed -i '/^set_id\>/d' ABC.txt       # Lines starting with the word 'set_id'
```

Comment: Would be a good idea to use word boundaries `\<set_id\>` to avoid matching other words contianing this string.